# Update on Android SQLite problems

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem when performing a routine update with SQLite from my application on Android, my code is as follows:

**Categoria.java**

```
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private int idCategoria;
    rivate String dscCategoria;    
    private int colorEtiqueta;

    public int getIdCategoria() {
        return idCategoria;
    }

    public void setIdCategoria(int idCategoria) {
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
    }

    public String getDscCategoria() {
        return dscCategoria;
    }

    public void setDscCategoria(String dscCategoria) {
        this.dscCategoria = dscCategoria;
    }    

    public int getColorEtiqueta() {
        return colorEtiqueta;
    }

    public void setColorEtiqueta(int colorEtiqueta) {
        this.colorEtiqueta = colorEtiqueta;
    }
}
```

**CategoriaController.java**

```
public class CategoriaController {

    private Context context;

    public CategoriaController(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }   

    public void actualizaCategoria(Categoria categoriasSel){
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        databaseHelper.modificaCategoria(categoriasSel);
    }
}
```

**Databasehelper.java**

```
    public class DatabaseHelper {

    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void modificaCategoria(Categoria categoria){
            UseDatabaseHelper useDatabaseHelper = new UseDatabaseHelper(context, "MyDataBase", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = useDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try{
                if(db != null){
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put("dsccategoria", categoria.getDscCategoria());
                    contentValues.put("color", categoria.getColorEtiqueta());
                    db.update("Categorias", contentValues, "Where idcategoria=" + categoria.getIdCategoria(), null);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if (db != null){
                    db.close();
                }
                if (useDatabaseHelper != null){
                    useDatabaseHelper.close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have no errors in the execution, but no updating is done, any ideas?

Comment: `db.update` returns the number of rows, that are affected. You can try to check if `db.update` returns 1. So you would know if it is really not updated.

Comment: If it doesn't return 1, then please add the part where you define the table for "Categorias".

Comment: thanks @mrtn, I just realized that I was not sending the correct data to the bean. Already resolved.